# NewLine Character for Unix

Tags: java, linux, unix

I have a Java Application running on Linux machine, it is generating a file  in which each record is separated by new line,

This file will be used by an application running on Unix SunOS system and  my code below does not generate proper file . I mean following code generates a file in which each line end with ^M charater when I open it with vi editor in Unix system

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
bw.write("\n");
```

Which character I have to write in order to see the file properly in Unix system.

Comment: Something is horribly wrong if the shown code generates a `\r\n` line ending. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file?

Comment: I suggest you use PrintWriter.println() and it will handle new lines for your.

Comment: @Herry I copy the file from Linux to Windows ,then to Unix. Does this operation manipulate the file?

Comment: @mmc18 Yes, the tool that you're using to transfer the file could change the line terminators. It depends on what tools you're using and how you're using them.

Comment: Can I use ftp tool copy file from linux to unix, or scp?

Comment: @mmc18 If you use ascii mode in ftp then it will modify line endings. If you edit the file in Windows it will also modify the line endings. In short, why go Linux > Windows > Unix?

Comment: linux->windows->unix path is not mandotory for me, I am just explaining what I did, actually the proper way is to ftp (bin mode) file from linux to unix right?

Comment: @mmc18 yes, binary mode makes sure the file is not changed. It should even work when you go via Windows (provided you don't touch the file with any Windows tools).

Answer (score 5):

The `\n` is the correct line ending for Unix. It's windows that uses `\r\n` as a line ending (with the `\r` or carriage return symbol) that looks like ^M. You can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) to get the correct line-ending for your system. You can also use `dos2unix` to remove dos formatted newlines from text files.

Comment: thanks for explanation but as I pointed out that I have already  added "\n" character.

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to remove the `\r` characters that you've added.